# Replace text between two patterns with spaces

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with the following format:-

```
abc
[1 20 30]

bdf
[23 45 68]

mng
[45 67 89]
```

....

I have to removed only the lines starting with [ and replace just that one white space left over by this deletion alone. How is this possible in Powershell?
Please help. Thanks

Comment: [1] please show a sample input AND the way that output should look. right now, _none_ of your sample data matches your description of what you want to remove. [*grin*] ///// [2] please put your sample data in code formatting.

Comment: what do you want the replace the "starts with a [" lines with? do you want to keep the blank lines? ///// seriously, my item [2] above covers an _important_ idea ... specificity.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far and where, specifically, you're stuck. For general guidance on writing questions, see [this help topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
##Store content in a variable 
$content = get-content path\to\foo.txt
$content -notmatch '\[\d+\s\d+\s\d+\]' | Out-File path\to\foo.txt -Force
```

Output would look like below

abc

bdf

mng